# restore documents which are stored as blobs in a sql database

Tags: sql-server, delphi, blob, documents

I've got an sql database from a customer. In the sql database is a table, called "documents". The documents are stored as blobs (have a look at the screenshot).

I want to restore the documents via Delphi (FileStream?). Do you have any ideas how to do that?

Regards,
Dennis Friedrich

[image: Screenshot table documents]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103437/delphi-load-image-save-as-blob-in-a-sql-database https://www.google.com/#q=delphi+blob

Comment: F: TFileStream;
begin
  F := TFileStream.Create('C:\Temp\test.dat', fmOutput);
  try
    AField.SaveToStream(F);
  finally
    F.Free;
  end;

Comment: use Navicat software for browse data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function SaveFieldBlobToFile(FQuery: TDataSet): boolean;
var MyStream : TMemoryStream;
begin
   Result:= false;
   MyStream:= TMemoryStream.Create;
   try
     (FQuery.Fieldbyname('MODELE') as TBlobField).SaveToStream(MyStream);
    if (MyStream<>nil) and (MyStream.Size > 0) then
    begin
      MyStream.Position := 0;
      MyStream.SaveToFile('C:\Temp\tempMyFile.zip');
      Result:= true;
    end
    else Result:= false;
  finally
    MyStream.Free;
  end;
end;


function LoadFileToBlob(FQuery: TDataSet): boolean;
var MyStream : TMemoryStream;
begin
  Result:= false;
  MyStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    MyStream.LoadFromFile('C:\Temp\tempMyFile.zip');
    MyStream.Position := 0;
    TryEdit(FQuery);
    (FQuery.FieldByName('MODELE') As TBlobField).LoadFromStream(MyStream);
    TryPost(FQuery);
    Result := True;
  finally
    MyStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Why use an intermediate memory stream?  Seems a bit pointless - just use the filestream directly.  What is `FZQuery`?  Typo?