# Different characters in TMemo lines compiling Delphi XE2 Delphi 10.2

Tags: delphi

I have migrated my application from Delphi XE2 to Delphi 10.2.3.

I have used this instruction to read a blob field into TMemo component:

```
Memo1.Text := AnNote.FieldByName('ANBLOB').Value
```

I see chinese characters in Delphi 10.2, and in Latin characters in Delphi XE2.

If I use this instruction:

```
Memo1.Lines.Text := AnNote.FieldByName('ANBLOB').AsString
```

I see the character in Latin alphabet in Delphi 10.2, 
why is this?

Comment: How is the blob encoded?

Comment: The Blob is a Firebird field with charset ISO 8859_1

Comment: Perhaps it's best to read it into a byte array and then decode manually. Which isn't completely trivial because that encoding isn't a standard one to be used with `TEncoding`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you can use `TEncoding.GetEncoding('ISO-8859-1')` or `TEncoding.GetEncoding(28591)`, just be sure to `Free()` the returned `TEncoding` object when you are done using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Memo1.Text := AnNote.FieldByName('ANBLOB').Value
>
> I see chinese characters in Delphi 10.2, and in Latin characters in Delphi XE2.

The `TField.Value` property returns a `Variant`.

In 10.2, that `Variant` likely contains just the raw data of the blob.  When converting such a `Variant` to a `String`, all charset information is lost. You get "Chinese characters" (commonly known as "Mojibake") when raw ANSI bytes are mis-interpreted as UTF-16 bytes.

In XE2, that `Variant` likely contains a pre-decoded `string` instead of raw blob bytes.

You *want* the database driver to decode strings for you, using the charset from the database field's metadata.  So you may be encountering a bug in the database driver in 10.2 that did not exist in XE2.

> Memo1.Lines.Text := AnNote.FieldByName('ANBLOB').AsString
>
> I see the character in Latin alphabet in Delphi 10.2, why is this?

`TField.AsString` allows the database driver to decode the field data using the field's charset metadata as needed.

Answer (score -2):

`Memo1.Text` is a `TCaption` (an alias for `UnicodeString`).

`FieldByName('FIELD').Value`  is a `Variant`.

It depends on your information that is stored in the blob field. `FieldByName('Field').AsString` converts your blob to a `String` if possible.

Hope that helps to answer your question: "why is this?"!

2 options for "how to do it":

1. you stay with `.AsString` if there was no special reason for switching to `.Value`.
2. handle different data types, like a Picture, as shown here:

   [Delphi load image save as blob in a sql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103437/)

Comment: `Memo1.Text` is not `WideString`. It is `string`, an alias for `UnicodeString`. The question probably cannot be answered yet, until more details are supplied.